# Can an `ExternalName` service point to the host machine?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm working locally (within Docker for Mac) on a Kubernetes cluster that will eventually be deployed to the cloud. We plan to use a database service in that environment. To simulate that, I'd like to have the services in the cluster connect to a database running outside the cluster on my laptop.

Can I do that? Here's what I thought I'd try.

- Define a `Service` with `type: ExternalName` and `externalName: somedb.local`
- Add `127.0.0.1 somedb.local` to `/etc/hosts` on the laptop

Is that correct? Is there a better way?

Comment: localhost on the host and in the pod are not the same localhost

Comment: @VasiliAngapov Yes, I know, but will a DNS lookup within the cluster "bubble up" to the host machine? If not, is there another way I could point to the host machine from within the cluster?

Answer (score 4):

After talking with some colleagues, I found a solution.

In Docker for Mac, `host.docker.internal` points to the host machine, and that lets me connect to the db running there, even from containers running in the K8s cluster.

Comment: Any idea if this would work from a k3d cluster? Since K8s is running in docker itself

Answer (score 0):

You may have a Service pointing to an address out of your SDN, by creating an Endpoint object with matching name.

```
----
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: external-db
  namespace: my-namespace
spec:
  ports:
  - name: exporter-3306
    port: 3306
  selector:
    name: external-db
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: external-db
  namespace: my-namespace
subsets:
- addresses:
  - ip: 10.42.253.110
  ports:
  - name: exporter-3306
    port: 3306
```

You may add hosts overrides in your Deployment definition:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      ...
      hostAliases:
      - ip: 10.42.253.110
        hostnames:
        - external-db
```

Comment: Does this work if the host machine doesn't have an ip other than 127.0.0.1?

Comment: A Kubernetes container querying 127.0.0.1 won't leave it's netnamespace. As a general rule with virtual/physical servers or containers : 127.0.0.1 won't ever get you to a remote host. If your external database only has a loopback address, then you have another issue.

Answer (score -1):

It seems the Kubernetes docs provide an instruction on how to achieve this.
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors

A note says endpoint IPs must not be: loopback (127.0.0.0/8 for IPv4, ::1/128 for IPv6), or link-local (169.254.0.0/16 and 224.0.0.0/24 for IPv4, fe80::/64 for IPv6).

Comment: Quilify as a comment.