# How do I make an external REST API (running in .Net on my host computer) accessible within K8s from a Service or ExternalName?

Tags: kubernetes, k3d

I have a REST API running locally on my laptop at `https://localhost:5001/something`. I want that to be reachable *inside* the Kubernetes cluster from a K8s DNS name. For example, an application running inside a Pod could use `some-service` instead of needing the entire Url.

Also, since `localhost` is relative to the host machine, how would I get the `Service` or `ExternalName` to reach `localhost` on the host machine, instead of inside the K8s cluster?

I tried `docker.host.internal` (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65942540)) but that didn't work.
And [this from K8s documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors) says that it can't be the loopback:

> The endpoint IPs must not be: loopback (127.0.0.0/8 for IPv4, ::1/128 for IPv6), or link-local (169.254.0.0/16 and 224.0.0.0/24 for IPv4, fe80::/64 for IPv6).

I'm running:

- **Host Machine:** Ubuntu 20.04
- **K8s:** k3d
- **Web API:** (.Net Core 3.1 on Linux, created by `dotnet new webapi MyAPI`)

Answer (score 0):

[Telepresence](https://www.telepresence.io/) is a tool created for that quick local testing your application with k8s cluster. It allows you to run single service locally while connecting it to remote Kubernetes cluster.

It substitutes a two-way network proxy for your normal pod running in the Kubernetes cluster. This pod proxies data from your Kubernetes environment (e.g., TCP connections, environment variables, volumes) to the local process. The local process has its networking transparently overridden so that DNS calls and TCP connections are routed through the proxy to the remote Kubernetes cluster.

Alternative way would be to create service that is being backed by `ssh server  running in a pod` and use reverse tunnel to open reverse connection to your local machine.

Comment: Is there no built-in way with k8s to do this?

Comment: For example, if I want to run a webhook and use `url` in the `MutatingWebhookConfiguration`, what would I put to get it to reach the API running on the same machine as the cluster?